# tkinter - Printing current input + by mistake also previous inputs

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am making a GUI in Tkinter and the code prints some attributes of a class.
However, something makes it print the attributes from the current instance but also from the previous ones (sorry if the jargon is wrong, I'm really new to this).

So in the Todo-list GUI I have created, I will enter a task and specify some attributes, then print all the attributes.
The task name is then displayed in a listbox and all the attributes of the task should be printed to terminal at the same time - however, this is where it will print the current attributes which I have just entered but also the attributes from the previously added task.

This is the code and the `print` command is in the `def show_task():` function.

```
from tkcalendar import * # Calendar module
import tkinter.messagebox # Import the messagebox module

task_list = []
task_types = ['Sparetime', 'School', 'Work']

class Task:
    def __init__(self, n, type_, i, m, p, h): #(h, w=8, p, u, n, v):
        self.name = n
        self.type = type_
        self.impact = i
        self.manageability = m
        self.proximity = p
        self.hours = h
        #self.connectivity = c
        ##self.work = w ##hours of work per day
        ##self.urgency = u
        ##self.note = n
        ##self.value = v

def show_tasks():
   # for widget in task_frame.winfo_children():
       # widget.destroy()

    for task in task_list:
        #listbox_tasks.insert(tkinter.END, *task_list) #(task_frame, text=f'{task.name} \n Type: {task.type} | Impact: {task.impact}| Manageability: {task.manageability} | Proximity: {task.proximity}').pack(fill='x')  
        print(
            'Task:'+task.name +
            '\n' +
            'Type:' + task.type + '\n' +
            'Impact:' + task.impact + '\n' +
            'Manageability:' + task.manageability + '\n' +
            'Proximity(Deadline):' + task.proximity + '\n' +
            'Hours:' + task.hours + '\n'
            )

def open_add_task():
    taskwin = Toplevel(root)
    taskwin.focus_force()
    
    #TITLE
    titlelabel = Label(taskwin, text='Title task concisely:').grid(column=1, row=0)
    name_entry = Entry(taskwin, width=40, justify='center')
    name_entry.grid(column=1, row=1)

    #TYPE
    typelabel = Label(taskwin, text='Type').grid(column=0, row=2)
    type_var = StringVar(value=task_types[2])
    OptionMenu(taskwin, type_var, *task_types).grid(column=0, row=3, sticky='nsew')

    #IMPACT
    impactlabel = Label(taskwin, text='Impact').grid(column=1, row=2)
    imp_var = StringVar(value=0)
    OptionMenu(taskwin, imp_var, *range(0, 10+1)).grid(column=1, row=3, sticky='ns')

    #MANAGEABILITY
    manlabel = Label(taskwin, text='Manageability').grid(column=2, row=2)
    man_var = StringVar(value=0)
    OptionMenu(taskwin, man_var, *range(0, 10+1)).grid(column=2, row=3, sticky='nsew')

    #PROXIMITY
    proximity_label = Label(taskwin, text = 'Choose a deadline', justify='center')
    proximity_label.grid(column=1, row=4)
    cal = Calendar(taskwin, selectmode='day', year=2021, month=4, day=27)
    cal.grid(column=1, row=5)
    def get_date():
        proximity_output_date.config(text=cal.get_date()) ##the .config didn't work until i did .grid(column=, row=) on seperate lines



    #HOURS(required)
    hourlabel = Label(taskwin, text='Whole hours \n required').grid(column=1, row=16)
    hour_entry = Entry(taskwin, width=4, justify='center')
    hour_entry.grid(column=1, row=17)

    def add_task():
        if name_entry.get() != '': # If textbox inputfield is NOT empty do this:
            task_list.append(Task(name_entry.get(), type_var.get(), imp_var.get(), man_var.get(), cal.get_date(), hour_entry.get()))
            show_tasks()
            listbox_tasks.insert(tkinter.END, name_entry.get())
            name_entry.delete(0, tkinter.END)
            taskwin.destroy()
        else:
            tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title='Whoops', message='You must enter a task')
        
    next_button = Button(taskwin, text='Next', command=add_task).grid(column=2, row=18, sticky='ew')
    

def sort_tasks():
    pass
def delete_task():
    pass
    #try:
        #task_index = listbox_tasks.curselection()[0]
        #listbox_tasks.delete(task_index)
    #except:
        #tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title='Oops', message='You must select a task to delete')

def save_tasks():
    pass
    #tasks = listbox_tasks.get(0, listbox_tasks.size())
    #pickle.dump(tasks, open('tasks.dat', 'wb'))
    


    
    
    
    

root = Tk()








task_frame = Frame()
# Create UI
your_tasks_label = Label(root, text='THESE ARE YOUR TASKS:', font=('Roboto',10, 'bold'), justify='center')
your_tasks_label.pack()


scrollbar_tasks = tkinter.Scrollbar(root)
scrollbar_tasks.pack(side=tkinter.RIGHT, fill=tkinter.Y)

listbox_tasks = tkinter.Listbox(root, height=10, width=50, font=('Roboto',10), justify='center') # tkinter.Listbox(where it should go, height=x, width=xx)
listbox_tasks.pack()

listbox_tasks.config(yscrollcommand=scrollbar_tasks.set)
scrollbar_tasks.config(command=listbox_tasks.yview)

try:
    #tasks = pickle.load(open('tasks.dat', 'rb'))
    listbox_tasks.delete(0, tkinter.END)
    for task in task_list:
        listbox_tasks.insert(tkinter.END, task)
except:
    tkinter.messagebox.showwarning(title='Phew', message='You have no tasks')

#BUTTONS
Add_Button = Button(root, text='Add New', width=42, command=open_add_task)
Add_Button.pack()

button_delete_task = Button(root, text='Delete task', width=42, command=delete_task)
button_delete_task.pack()


button_save_tasks = Button(root, text='Save tasks', width=42, command=save_tasks)
button_save_tasks.pack()

#sort_type = StringVar(value='All')
#OptionMenu(btn_frame, sort_type, 'All', *task_types).grid(column=0, row=0, sticky='nsew')

#sort_imp = StringVar(value='Any')
#OptionMenu(btn_frame, sort_imp,'Any', *range(0, 10+1)).grid(column=1, row=0, sticky='nsew')

#Button(btn_frame, text='Sort', command=sort_tasks).grid(column=1, row=1, sticky='nsew')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Because there's a `for` loop in `show_tasks()` which prints all the tasks in the `task_list`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
for task in task_list:
```

with:

```
task = task_list[-1]
```

since you want to print details for a single task and not every task in the list.  You'll also want to unindent the print statement.